# Error using node.js with async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, raspberry-pi3, async.js

I am running Node v4.2.1 with npm v2.14.7 on a raspberry pi 3. The project is a browser controlled node js robot running on javascript.

I get this error:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:228
    return supportsSymbol && fn[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction';
```

Followed by :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at isAsync (/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:228:32)
    at wrapAsync (/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:232:12)
    at /home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3866:9
    at eachOfArrayLike (/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1055:9)
    at eachOf (/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1103:5)
    at _parallel (/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3865:5)
    at Object.parallelLimit [as parallel] (/home/pi/rover/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3948:5)
    at Object.tank.moveForward (/home/pi/rover/app.js:46:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pi/rover/app.js:87:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

The code is around 5 years old so I am pretty sure the code needs to be updated.

App.js Code :

```
    var express = require('express'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path'),
  async = require('async'),
  gpio = require('pi-gpio'),
  app = express();

//set the port
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//serve static files from /static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static')));

//create the server
var http = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

//init socket.io
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//the actual tank code starts here
//----------------------------------

//create the tank object
var tank = {

  //assign pin numbers to variables for later use
  motors: {
    leftFront: 11,
    leftBack: 12,
    rightFront: 15,
    rightBack: 16
  },

  //open the gpio pins and set them as outputs
  init: function(){
    gpio.open(this.motors.leftFront, "output");
    gpio.open(this.motors.leftBack, "output");
    gpio.open(this.motors.rightFront, "output");
    gpio.open(this.motors.rightBack, "output");
  },

  //for moving forward we power both motors  
  moveForward: function(){
    async.parallel([
      gpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, 1),
      gpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, 1)
    ]);
  },

  //for moving backward we power both motors but in backward mode
  moveBackward: function(){
    async.parallel([
      gpio.write(this.motors.leftBack, 1),
      gpio.write(this.motors.rightBack, 1)
    ]);
  },

  //for turning right we power the left motor 
  moveLeft: function(){
    gpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, 1);
  },

  //for turning left we power the right motor
  moveRight: function(){
    gpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, 1)
  },

  //stop both motors in all directions 
  stop: function(){
    async.parallel([
      gpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, 0),
      gpio.write(this.motors.leftBack, 0),
      gpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, 0),
      gpio.write(this.motors.rightBack, 0)
    ]);
  }
};

//listen for socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //listen for move signal
  socket.on('move', function(direction) {
    switch(direction){
     case 'up':
        tank.moveForward();
        break;
      case 'down':
        tank.moveBackward();
        break;
      case 'left':
        tank.moveLeft();
        break;
      case 'right':
        tank.moveRight();
        break;
    }
  });
  //listen for stop signal
  socket.on('stop', function(dir){
    tank.stop();
  });
});

tank.init();
```

Comment: What is that `gpio.write` function? Does it really return an asynchronous function that takes a callback? I have the feeling that nothing in your code is actually asynchronous and you should drop all those `async.parallel` calls.

Comment: my understanding of the write function is where the motors are being setup to move the tank robot. I understood needing the async so that both motors would be moved at the same time.

Comment: If you want to have a look, I am trying to follow this project :

Comment: https://github.com/mirceageorgescu/raspi-tank-2/

Comment: No, you don't need `async` to move both at the same time. The command just puts both pins to on, then both motors will run. The `pi-gpio` library seems to support callbacks, but it's not clear when they are called. You need `async.parallel` only if you want to wait for multiple calls to finish, but your code doesn't seem to need that - and if it did, it doesn't work - I suggest studying the `async.js` docs. Just try whether it works as expected when you drop the `async.parallel` call.

Comment: So just remove that line? I'm really not trying to be stubborn, but could you show me an example of what to remove? I will definitely be studying up on the async.js stuff. I do really appreciate your input

Comment: Just `moveForward() {
      gpio.write(this.motors.leftFront, 1); 
      gpio.write(this.motors.rightFront, 1); }` etc. No `async` usage.

Comment: That was it! Well maybe... at least no errors. Now I just have to actually test on the robot. Thank you